# RuntimeException A facade root has not been set. Tratando de llamar un Procedimiento almacenado

Tags: mysql, laravel, leaf

Estoy tratando de hacer una **API** en el framework de **`PHP`** `Leaf 3.0` (similar a Laravel). En `"controllers"` tengo un método que llama un listado de enfermedades, pero cuando lo llamo me manda un error: `RuntimeException A facade root has not been set`. No entiendo porque, la verdad.

Código en: **_app.php**:

```
<?php

app()->get("/", function () {
    response()->json(["message" => "Leaf API"]);
});

app()->get('/Enfermedad', 'EnfermedadController@listarenfermeades');

app()->get("/app", function () {
    // app() returns $app
    response()->json(app()->routes());
});
```

Código en **EnfermedadController.php**:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Controllers;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

    class EnfermedadController extends Controller{
            
        public function listarenfermeades(){   

            $sql = new DB; 
            $result = $sql::select("CALL SP_Ver_Todas_enfermedades_lista()");
            response()->json($result);
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

Ya intenté en la documentación y para ser sincero no entiendo. La conexión, de la BD está en el archivo **.env**. Tengo entendido que la estructura para tomar la ruta de la BD va ahí. Y están correctos los datos (las credenciales, la BD está en MySQL y el SP ahí está y funciona) ¿Cómo puedo resolver esto?.

Solución:

1.- Hay que instalar en el proyecto db. En la terminal, hay que instalar: composer require leafs/db

2.- Según la documentación, hay que usar "db()->connect('127.0.0.1', 'test');" Aquí se pone la conexión DB que necesites

3.- En mi caso hice esto para acceder al SP:

```js
public function listarenfermeades(){  
               
               db()->connect('127.0.0.1', 'mibd', 'uusariodelaBD', 'ClavedelaBD');              
               $queryResult = db()->query("CALL SP_Ver_Todas_enfermedades_lista()")->get();
               $result = collect($queryResult);
               response()->json($result);
               return $result;

            }
```

Entiendo, que debe de existir una opción aún más eficiente para hacer dichos llamados, pero, tengo unas horas aprendiendo esto. Espero, que esto sea de utilidad para alguien más. Gracias user327285.

Moderadores: Espero, que agreguen Leaf en las opciones de las preguntas para que también dicho marco sea parte de las etiquetas de las indagatorias.

Saludos.

Comment: Es posible que ese error sea generado porque no es posible de alguna manera consultar un procedimiento almacenado de esa forma, puedes intentar talvez tratarlo como una colección, como lo indica https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#introduction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta usar `collect` desde `Illuminate\Support\Collection` para consultar de manera correcta un procedimiento almacenado de esta forma:

```
$queryResult = DB::select("CALL SP_Ver_Todas_enfermedades_lista()");
$result = collect($queryResult);
response()->json($result);
return $result;
```

**EDIT**:
`Leaf` provee una interfaz de base de datos, la guía es sencilla y la puedes encontrar aquí [leafphp.dev/modules/db/#installing-leaf-db](https://leafphp.dev/modules/db/#installing-leaf-db).

Luego de que lo hayas instalado, cuentas con tres diferentes opciones para realizar la conexión a tu base de datos, así que supongo que el método `db()->autoConnect();` sera utilizado en este caso, luego realizas la consulta, fíjate bien en colocar la sentencia correcta `db()->select()...`, esto seria el ejemplo que dejas en la descripción, espero te sirva.

Comment: Hola, @user327285. Gracias por tú respuesta. Te comento que no, no funciono. Marca exactamente lo mismo ["RuntimeException 
…\vendor\illuminate\support\Facades\Facade.php258"]   Puse abajo de :"use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;" puse: "use Illuminate\Support\Collection;" y puse las líneas tal como las pusiste y no funciono.

Comment: Hasta hice una consulta con en lugar del SP y también marca el mismo error.

Comment: Creo que podrías solucionarlo usando la DB que provee Leaf

Comment: Lo estoy viendo. Gracias.